# Scala Why am I getting a type mismatch with hashmap?

Tags: scala

I am getting a type mismatch here?
Am I not create a HashMap of key char and value int?
Is i some type of iterator instead of a int?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

object Solution {
    def firstUniqChar(s: String): Int = {
        var hashMapName =        HashMap[Char, Int]();
        for (i <- 0 until s.length){
             if (hashMapName.contains(s.charAt(i)) ) return i-1
            else hashMapName = hashMapName + (s.charAt(i), i)
            println(s.charAt(i))
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, are you sure about this implementation? It looks like this returns the first _non_ unique character, which seem to not be consistent with the name of the method.

Comment: Please don't mix a mutable collection with a mutable variable, use either of them.

Comment: A one line solution: `def firstUniqChar(s: String): Int = 
        s.indexWhere(c => s.lastIndexOf(c) == s.indexOf(c))`

Answer (score 4):

In Scala everything is a method call, including what looks like operators.

That means that

```
hashMapName + (s.charAt(i), i)
```

is ambiguous to the parser, because it's unclear whether you are using the operator syntax or the method syntax, which would be

```
hashMapName.+(s.charAt(i), i)
```

In order to fix the error you have to add an extra pair of parentheses to clarify that you are not trying to invoke a method with two arguments but a method with a one argument, which happens to be a pair

```
hashMapName + ((s.charAt(i), i))
```

Comment: oh, my! Maybe I am more over my head with scala than I first thought.

Comment: @GarrettPeuse other option would be `hashMapName + (s.charAt(i) -> i)`

Comment: @MeditationOrBust Don't worry!  Scala is very different than Java, C#, etc.  The scalac compiler is extremely complex and has so much richness; it requires a lot of reading and practice to get the "feel".  Don't give up; you will be rewarded.